# How to add items of a class to an array in c++ without giving them a name

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I am trying to make a game in c++, and I would like to add bullets to an array but not give them a name. In javascript, I would be able to do something like:

```
var bullets =[]
bullets.push(new bullet(x,y))
```

How would I do something similar in c++; creating a new object in a class without giving it a name and also adding it to an array?

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<bullet> bullets;
bullets.push_back(bullet(x, y));
```

or

```
vector<shared_ptr<bullet>> bullets;
bullets.push_back(new bullet(x, y));
```

Depending on whether you want to store values or references. Generally, in C++ you want to think about object ownership, and so there are different pointer types, including `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, `auto_ptr`, and `weak_ptr` to facilitate this. `shared_ptr` is the most flexible type, but also carries some performance overhead.

Comment: I'd generally avoid shared_ptr unless you have reason to not know anything aobut ownership. Stick to unique_ptr for a case like this.

Comment: @Charlie, it might be a premature optimization for someone moving from javascript.

Comment: I see shared_ptr lead to bugs more often than not. Usually it's not expressing what you want, or ends up with surprising results later on. Better to avoid it unless you know you need it.